# after deleting some sites and sites-goup i get a php warning "Undefined array key 2"

Tags: craft4

I deleted some sites and also a site-group i did'nt need anymore and now getting a php warning "Undefined array key 2"
and i can not open entries anymore.
seems that group id (or site ids) or not found/correct anymore?

also, if i want to resave the entries, i get the same error in the terminal.
[image]
[image]

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the issue by myself.
Before deleting a site within the site settings (settings -> sites)
i had to disable/deactive a site within the settings of a section, wait until all entries are automatically saved again and then delete a site.
Not sure if this is the expected behavoir, i think in the past i just deleted a site right away in the settings.